# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy intentando extraer los datos de una cabaña dada (debe ser un número entero: 1, 2, 3, ... n).

**¿Por qué me dice que no está definido "imagenes" en el archivo Cabanas.php?**
He definido var_dump($datos); para que me diga que obtiene:(¿no debería obtener 4 resultados, debido a que todos los datos son idénticos menos las imagenes (al haber 4 imagenes)? ¿Solo muestra uno?

```
array(12) { 
 ["idcabana"]=> string(1) "1" 
 [0]=> string(1) "1" 
 ["nombre"]=> string(7) "CABAÑA1" 
 [1]=> string(7) "CABAÑA1" 
 ["capacidad"]=> string(1) "9" 
 [2]=> string(1) "9" 
 ["descripcion"]=> string(57) "HABITACIÓN DE CABAÑA MUY GRANDE CON TODOS LOS ACCESORIOS." 
 [3]=> string(57) "HABITACIÓN DE CABAÑA MUY GRANDE CON TODOS LOS ACCESORIOS." 
 ["precio"]=> string(6) "150.00" 
 [4]=> string(6) "150.00" 
 ["ruta"]=> string(13) "cabana1_1.jpg" 
 [5]=> string(13) "cabana1_1.jpg" 
}
```

Tengo los siguientes métodos:

```
static public function datosCabana($idcabana){
        //Realizamos la consulta.
        $ejecucion = self::Conexion();
        $registro = $ejecucion->query("SELECT c.idcabana, c.nombre, c.capacidad, c.descripcion, c.precio, i.ruta FROM cabanas as c, imagenes as i
                                   WHERE c.idcabana=i.idcabana AND idcabana=$idcabana");
        //Guardamos la fila de la consulta.
        $datos = $registro->fetch();
        //Creamos un objeto de la clase Cabanas con los datos.
        $micabana = new Cabanas($datos);
        //Pasamos el cliente a la funcion mostrarCabana();.
        $micabana->mostrarCabana();
    }

static public function obtenerImagenesCabana($idcabana){
        //Realizamos la consulta.
        $ejecucion = self::Conexion();
        $sql = "SELECT ruta FROM imagenes WHERE idcabana=$idcabana";
        $registro = $ejecucion->query($sql);
        //Creamos una array de imagenes.
        $imagenes = array();
        //Mientras haya datos los guardamos...
        while($datos = $registro->fetch()){
            //Array asociativo: al array $imagenes le pasamos la imagen concreta.
            array_push($imagenes, $datos["ruta"]);
        }
        //Devolvemos el array de imagenes.
        return $imagenes;
    }
```

**Clase Cabañas:**

```
<?php

/**
 * Clase Cabañas.
 */
class Cabanas {
    private $idcabana;
    private $nombre;
    private $capacidad;
    private $descripcion;
    private $precio;
    private $imagenes; //Array

    /**
     * Constructor de la clase Cabanas.
     * @param type $row
     */
    public function __construct($row){
        $this->idcabana = $row["idcabana"];
        $this->nombre = $row["nombre"];
        $this->capacidad = $row["capacidad"];
        $this->descripcion = $row["descripcion"];
        $this->precio = $row["precio"];
        $this->imagenes = $row["imagenes"];
    }

    function getIdcabana() {
        return $this->idcabana;
    }

    function getNombre() {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    function getCapacidad() {
        return $this->capacidad;
    }

    function getDescripcion() {
        return $this->descripcion;
    }

    function getPrecio() {
        return $this->precio;
    }

    function getImagenes() {
        return $this->imagenes;
    }

    function setIdcabana($idcabana) {
        $this->idcabana = $idcabana;
    }

    function setNombre($nombre) {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
    }

    function setCapacidad($capacidad) {
        $this->capacidad = $capacidad;
    }

    function setDescripcion($descripcion) {
        $this->descripcion = $descripcion;
    }

    function setPrecio($precio) {
        $this->precio = $precio;
    }

    function setImagenes($imagenes) {
        $this->imagenes = $imagenes;
    }


    function mostrarCabana(){
        echo $this->idcabana;
        echo $this->nombre;
        echo $this->capacidad;
        echo $this->descripcion;
        echo $this->precio;
    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Haz probado la consulta en la consola de SQL para ver si te arroja resultados ? has probado que $idcabana si te lleve el id ?

Comment: No me arroja resultados debido a que me sale el error: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

Comment: Por lo mismo te digo que pruebes la consulta en la consola SQL, fetch() espera datos al no recibirlos saca ese error, es decir tu error esta en la consulta

Comment: La consulta está bien debido a que me muestra datos desde el entorno visual de phpmyadmin SQL. SELECT c.idcabana, c.nombre, c.capacidad, c.descripcion, c.precio, i.ruta FROM cabanas as c, imagenes as i WHERE c.idcabana=i.idcabana AND c.idcabana=1 FUNCIONA

Comment: En la SQL me funciona, solo que a la hora de ejecutar el .php en el servidor /localhost/ me tira ese error.

Comment: @CamiloVasquez Estoy tratando de reducir el error pero me sigue saliendo lo siguiente: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\daw\pruebas.php on line 10, esto a la hora de imprimir lo que devuelve la consulta.

Comment: @omaza1990  `$imagenes` no es un Array,  solo cuando lo declaras luego cuando lo asignas deja de serlo pues no añades elementos directamente reemplazar el valor, por lo que si intentas recorrerlo con un foreach te dará ese error. Fijate `$this->imagenes = $row["imagenes"];`

Comment: ¿Entonces cómo se podría modificar para que fuera un array y almacene las imágenes de cada cabaña?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si ejecutas:

```
SELECT c.idcabana, c.nombre, c.capacidad, c.descripcion, c.precio, i.ruta FROM cabanas as c, imagenes as i
WHERE c.idcabana=i.idcabana AND idcabana=1
```

Debiera decirte que `idcabana` es ambiguo. Debiera ser, en cambio

```
SELECT c.idcabana, c.nombre, c.capacidad, c.descripcion, c.precio, i.ruta FROM cabanas as c, imagenes as i
WHERE c.idcabana=i.idcabana AND c.idcabana=1
```

Comment: Aún así me sigue saliendo el mismo error.

Comment: ¿A qué se debe mi error?

Comment: Si cambiaste la query poniendo `c.idcabana` entonces hay que ir descartando otras posibilidades. Hacer un `var_dump($registro)` para comprobar que sea `false`. Hacer un `var_dump` a la conexión para ver que sea un objeto PDO válido ( o mysqli, no sé qué estás usando...)

Comment: También podrías configurar la conexión para que tire excepciones en vez de fallar silenciosamente. Eso, de nuevo, depende del driver que estés usando

Comment: Con var_dump($datos); me da "NULL". No creo que sea motivo de excepciones (try-catch) sino que no sé porque motivo me dice que no existe imagenes cuando sí lo tengo incluido en el fichero Cabanas.php y en la función.

Comment: Edité la pregunta con la opción del "var_dump".

Comment: Vas a tener que mostrarnos tu singleton de `Conexion`. Aparentemente su método `query` no devuelve un cursor sino que hace `fetch` del primer registro.

Comment: La conexión está bien debido a que otras funciones tiran de la Conexion y funciona. Lo que ocurre es que debe ser un arreglo/array imagenes pero no lo encuentra en la clase. Mira el chat.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69729/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-amenadiel).

Comment: Ya no entiendo la pregunta. Originalmente era que el fetch te decía `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object`, yo estaba respondiendo a eso. Debieras haber dejado esta pregunta como resuelta y hacer otra con la segunda anomalía. Ahora si un visitante X entra encontrará que mi respuesta no tiene nada que ver con el error